# Methods to properly cut a large fits file to isolate certain galaxies into smaller fits files

Tags: python-3.x, astronomy, astropy, fits

Currently I am working on analyzing several galaxies within a fits file image. The fits file is a 3D Hyperspectral cube, with x and y axes representing Right Ascension and Declination, and a z axis representing frequency. I also know the precise right ascension and declination of each galaxy. My goal is to cut the large fits file into smaller ones that isolate each of the galaxies so I can perform some further analysis on the individual galaxies. A crude and brute force method would simply be to manually cut the fits files around galaxy, and my currently algorithm is crude by simply cutting a square of a certain number of pixels around a galaxy, but I want to ask if theres some astropy method or some other numerical/mathematical method to identify and cut around the galaxies more efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [spectral-cube](https://spectral-cube.readthedocs.io/) and [photutils](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/) Python packages.

spectral-cube has methods to cut out sub cubes (see e.g. [here](https://spectral-cube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manipulating.html#extracting-a-subcube-from-a-ds9-region)), and photutils has methods to detect sources (see [here](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/detection.html)) and more, e.g. to measure and analyse your sources. For photutils, some of the methods will only work for 2D, and you will need to do some Numpy expressions to work with your 3D data.

In general, all Python astronomy packages (Astropy, spectral-cube, photutils) will work with pixel data in Numpy arrays (e.g. read with `astropy.io.fits`) and sky coordinates using `astropy.wcs.WCS` and `astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord` objects, so you will have to learn those a bit. For that a good place to start is the [Astropy tutorials](https://astropy-tutorials.readthedocs.io/).

You asked for an efficient way to do the cutouts. This is achieved by using a Numpy array feature to "slice" into the large 3D pixel data array and to create a "view" of that cutout without making a copy. If you're new to Numpy, a good starting point to learn is the "basics of Numpy arrays" page of the [Python data science handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/).

Answer (score 0):

[Astropy has a Cutout2D](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.nddata.Cutout2D.html) class that is useful for this. While it can read in FITS files with more than two axes, it can only produce a cutout based on two of the axes.